# How to fix the following ubuntu error when trying to create a minecraft server

Tags: minecraft

[The output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O4rfb.png)

How to fix this error? I dont know what i should try so... yeah i didnt tried much...

Hope someone can help

I use a .sh file with `screen -AmdS paper java -Xmx7000M -jar paper-1.19.jar`  to run it.

Comment: **Welcome to the Ask Ubuntu community.** To make it easier to troubleshoot your issue, please edit your question and include the version of the Ubuntu OS that you're running. Thanks